# viewholder does not maintain its state when scrolled off screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-cursor

I have a music player app where when an item is clicked it changes its state to 'play' state where it gets expanded to show a seek bar and other changes also take place and vice versa.

The problem is whenever I scroll up or down, the view holder swaps its current state(playing, paused visibility in this case)  with some other random view in the list. It is also worth mentioning that this is consistent throughout the list so after every certain number of view holders, the state is the same as the one that was clicked (so if view at position 0 is in play visibility state after every 10 views a view is in the same state, note however the song still plays for the right one).

Here is the Adapter code (extends from a base adapter and the methods for play/pause visibility can be found here which are used in the song fragment code below):

```
    public class AllSongsAdapter extends BaseSongAdapter<AllSongsAdapter.AllSongsItemHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Song> songList;

    public AllSongsAdapter(){
        super(null);
    }

    //OnCreateViewHolder was called for every view;
    //FIX: return 0 for same type of views.
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    //cursor moves to the appropriate position in the list so we just have to update our views
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AllSongsItemHolder holder, Cursor cursor) {
        if(cursor!=null) {
            int i = cursor.getPosition();
            Log.d("on Bind", "i:" + i);
            Song songItem = songList.get(i);

            holder.songItemName.setText(songItem.title);
            holder.songItemArtistName.setText(songItem.artistName);
            holder.songItemAlbumName.setText(songItem.albumName);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
        super.swapCursor(newCursor);
        songList = SongsLoader.getSongsForCursor(newCursor);
    }

    @Override
    public AllSongsItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.d("CREATE VIEW HOLDER", "holder" );

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.songs_item_list, parent, false);
        return new AllSongsItemHolder(v);
    }

    private Uri getAlbumArtUri(long albumId) {
        return ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart"), albumId);
    }


    public void setPlayVisibility(View child, RecyclerView rv) {
        //View v = rv.getChildAt(rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
        AllSongsItemHolder holder = (AllSongsItemHolder) rv.getChildViewHolder(child);

       // if(getItemId(position) == rv.getChildItemId(v)){}

            holder.seekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.songItemTimer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.songItemImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
            holder.songItemImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#303F9F"));


    }
    public void setPauseVisibility(View child,  RecyclerView rv) {
        //View v = rv.getChildAt(rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
        AllSongsItemHolder holder = (AllSongsItemHolder) rv.getChildViewHolder(child);

        //if(getItemId(position) == rv.getChildItemId(v)){}

            holder.seekBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.songItemTimer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            holder.songItemImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            holder.songItemImage.setBackgroundColor(0);


    }




    static class AllSongsItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView songItemImage, songItemOptionDropDown;
        private TextView songItemName, songItemAlbumName, songItemArtistName;
        private View separator;

        private SeekBar seekBar;
        private ImageView nowPlayingIcon;
        private TextView songItemTimer;

        public AllSongsItemHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            songItemImage = v.findViewById(R.id.songItemImage);
            songItemOptionDropDown = v.findViewById(R.id.songItemOptionDropDown);

            songItemAlbumName = v.findViewById(R.id.songItemAlbumName);
            songItemArtistName = v.findViewById(R.id.songItemArtistName);
            songItemName = v.findViewById(R.id.songItemName);
            separator = v.findViewById(R.id.separator);

            seekBar = v.findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
            songItemTimer = v.findViewById(R.id.songItemTimer);
           // nowPlayingIcon = v.findViewById(R.id.nowPlayingIcon);

        }
    }
}
```

I noticed that when getItemViewType returns position this problem does not occur because recycler view holds an instance for every item in the list. But clearly this is not an adequate solution because it slows down the scrolling when first loaded as it has to create every view. Could be something to do with this?

BaseAdapter code:

```
public abstract class BaseSongAdapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {


    protected Cursor mCursor;
    protected int mRowIDColumn;
    protected boolean mDataValid;



    public BaseSongAdapter(Cursor c) {
        init(c);
    }

    public BaseSongAdapter() {}


    void init(Cursor c) {
        boolean cursorPresent = c != null;
        mCursor = c;
        mDataValid = cursorPresent;
        mRowIDColumn = cursorPresent ? c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id") : -1;
        setHasStableIds(true);

        if(mDataValid && mCursor!=null) {
            Log.d("VALID", "CURSOR");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position) {
        //Log.d("ON BIND","CALLED");
        if (!mDataValid) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot bind viewholder when cursor is in invalid state.");
        }
        if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not move cursor to position " + position + " when trying to bind viewholder");
        }

        onBindViewHolder(holder, mCursor);

    }

    public abstract void onBindViewHolder(VH holder, Cursor cursor);

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        if (mDataValid) {
            return mCursor.getCount();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        if (!mDataValid) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot lookup item id when cursor is in invalid state.");
        }
        if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not move cursor to position " + position + " when trying to get an item id");
        }

        return mCursor.getLong(mRowIDColumn);
    }

    public void swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
        if (newCursor == mCursor) {
            return;
        }

        //Log.d("TAG", "swapCursor");

        //Cursor oldCursor = mCursor;
        if (newCursor != null) {
            mCursor = newCursor;
            mRowIDColumn = newCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id");
            mDataValid = true;
            // notify the observers about the new cursor
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            mCursor = null;
            mRowIDColumn = -1;
            mDataValid = false;
            // notify the observers about the lack of a data set
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, getItemCount());
        }
        //return oldCursor;
    }



}
```

Song Fragment code where clicks are handled(in onActivityCreated):

```
public class AllSongsFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private final int LOADER_ID_ALLSONGS = 0;

    private Context ctx;
    private AllSongsAdapter mAdapter;
    private MediaPlayerHolder mediaPlayerHolder;

    //on click play,pause variables
    private boolean playingCLicked = false;
    private boolean firstTime = true;
    private String playbackState;
    private View lastChildView;
    private long currentSongId;
    private long newID;
    private long nextID; //id for next song
    private int lastTrackPosition; //for auto next track

    private RecyclerView rv;

    public AllSongsFragment() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID_ALLSONGS, null, this);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_songs_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        rv = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragmentList);

        mediaPlayerHolder = new MediaPlayerHolder(getActivity());
        mediaPlayerHolder.setPlaybackInfoListener(new PlaybackListener());


        rv.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), rv, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void click(View view, final int position) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onClick " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                newID = mAdapter.getItemId(position);
                if (playingCLicked) {
                    if (mediaPlayerHolder.isPlaying()) {
                        if (currentSongId == newID) {
                            mAdapter.setPauseVisibility(view, rv);
                            lastChildView = view;
                        }

                        //PAUSE IT
                        mediaPlayerHolder.pause();

                        Log.d("playingclicked", "true" + "state" + playbackState);
                        //when a different song is clicked while current song is playing
                        if (playbackState.equalsIgnoreCase("paused") && newID != currentSongId) {
                            currentSongId = newID;
                            mAdapter.setPauseVisibility(lastChildView, rv);
                            mAdapter.setPlayVisibility(view, rv);
                            mediaPlayerHolder.reset();
                            mediaPlayerHolder.loadMedia(currentSongId);
                            mediaPlayerHolder.play();

                            lastTrackPosition = position;
                            lastChildView = view;
                            Log.d("else 1 positions", "currentsongID" + currentSongId + "lasttrack" + lastTrackPosition);
                        }

                        playingCLicked = !playingCLicked;
                    } else { //media is not playing
                        Log.d("else 1", "play");
                        if (firstTime) {
                            Log.d("different", "no");
                            currentSongId = newID;
                            lastTrackPosition = position;
                            lastChildView = view;
                            mediaPlayerHolder.reset();
                            mediaPlayerHolder.loadMedia(currentSongId);

                            Log.d("SelectedTrack", "" + mediaPlayerHolder.getMediaPlayer().getSelectedTrack(MEDIA_TRACK_TYPE_AUDIO));
                            firstTime = false;
                        }

                        if (newID != currentSongId) {
                            Log.d("different", "yes");
                            //mediaPlayerHolder.stop();
                            currentSongId = newID;
                            mediaPlayerHolder.reset();
                            mediaPlayerHolder.loadMedia(currentSongId);
                            firstTime = true;
                        }
                        if (currentSongId == newID)
                            mAdapter.setPlayVisibility(view, rv);

                        //PLAY IT
                        mediaPlayerHolder.play();

                        playingCLicked = !playingCLicked;
                    }

                } else //----------playingclicked = false, first called--------------
                {
                    if (!mediaPlayerHolder.isPlaying()) {
                        lastChildView = view;
                        mAdapter.setPlayVisibility(view, rv);


                        if (firstTime) {
                            Log.d("different", "no, first time");
                            currentSongId = newID;
                            lastTrackPosition = position;
                            lastChildView = view;
                            mediaPlayerHolder.reset();
                            mediaPlayerHolder.loadMedia(currentSongId);

                            Log.d("SelectedTrack", "" + mediaPlayerHolder.getMediaPlayer().getSelectedTrack(MEDIA_TRACK_TYPE_AUDIO));
                            firstTime = false;
                        }

                        Log.d("playbackState", playbackState + "currentId " + currentSongId);

                        //called when current song is paused and after playingClicked = true following is called if songId is different
                        if (newID != currentSongId) {
                            Log.d("different", "yes");
                            currentSongId = newID;
                            mediaPlayerHolder.stop();
                            mediaPlayerHolder.reset();
                            mediaPlayerHolder.loadMedia(currentSongId);
                        }

                        //PLAY IT
                        mediaPlayerHolder.play();

                        playingCLicked = !playingCLicked;

                    } else { //media is playing
                        Log.d("else 2", "pause");
                        if (newID == currentSongId) {
                            lastChildView = view;
                            lastTrackPosition = position;
                            mAdapter.setPauseVisibility(view, rv);
                        }

                        //PAUSE IT
                        mediaPlayerHolder.pause();
                        firstTime = false;

                        //when a different song is clicked while current song is playing
                        if (playbackState.equalsIgnoreCase("paused") && newID != currentSongId) {
                            currentSongId = newID;
                            mAdapter.setPauseVisibility(lastChildView, rv);
                            mAdapter.setPlayVisibility(view, rv);
                            mediaPlayerHolder.reset();
                            mediaPlayerHolder.loadMedia(currentSongId);
                            mediaPlayerHolder.play();

                            lastTrackPosition = position;
                            lastChildView = view;

                            Log.d("else 2 positions", "currentsongID" + currentSongId + "lasttrack" + lastTrackPosition);
                        }

                        playingCLicked = !playingCLicked;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"onLongClick " + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }));

        mAdapter = new AllSongsAdapter();
        rv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        //------------Temporary divider-----------------
        RecyclerView.ItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), layoutManager.getOrientation());
        rv.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);

    }


    @Override
    public Loader onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        Log.d("CREATE LOADER", "SUCCESS");
        Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        final String[] PROJECTION = {"_id", "title", "artist", "album", "duration", "track", "artist_id", "album_id"};

        return new CursorLoader(ctx,
                musicUri,
                PROJECTION,
                null,
                null,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER );
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(data);

        Log.d("LOAD FINISHED", "SUCCESS");
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {
        Log.d("LOADER RESET", "CALLED");
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }



    class PlaybackListener extends PlaybackStateListener{

        @Override
        void onDurationChanged(int duration) {
            super.onDurationChanged(duration);
        }

        @Override
        void onPositionChanged(int position) {
            super.onPositionChanged(position);
        }

        @Override
        void onStateChanged(int state) {
            playbackState = PlaybackListener.convertStateToString(state);
        }

        @Override
        void onPlaybackCompleted() {
            //super.onPlaybackCompleted();
            //pause visibility after completed
            mAdapter.setPauseVisibility(lastChildView, rv);
        }

        @Override
        void onLogUpdated(String formattedMessage) {
            super.onLogUpdated(formattedMessage);
        }
    }

//---------------RECYCLER VIEW TOUCH EVENTS LISTENER CLASS------------------------
    class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

        private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
        private ClickListener mListener;


        public RecyclerTouchListener(Context ctx, final RecyclerView recyclerView, ClickListener clickListener){
            mListener = clickListener;

            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureDetector.OnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

                }

                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                   // Log.d("GESTURE DETECTED", "ACTION UP" + e);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    //Log.d("GESTURE DETECTED", "LONG PRESS");

                    if(rv.getScrollState() == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && !(rv.getScrollState() == SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING)) {
                        View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                        if (child != null && mListener != null) {
                            mListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(child));
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
           //Log.d("Intercept Event", "INTERCEPTING \n" + e);

            if(rv.getScrollState() == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && !(rv.getScrollState() == SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING)) {
                View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && mListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                    mListener.click(child, rv.getChildLayoutPosition(child));
                }
            }

            //true if onTouchEvent is to be called, false if you want gesture detector to handle events
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }


    }


}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be setting the play/pause/whatever visibility in onBindViewHolder or else it will be whatever the last setting was even though a new model object is bound to that view.

Comment: understandable, are you also suggesting that I should call my click listener in the adapters view holder or shall I get a reference somehow to the view that is clicked and set the visibility in onBind for it? how will i go about implementing the latter?

Comment: I normally set the specific click listener in onBindViewHolder because you need to know the specific item.

Comment: Thanks for your help I figured it out. I got the currently playing tracks position in onClickListener implemented in the view holder. Then from there I could set the visibility for the currently playing track to visible if the holders position equalled to that of the current track, else set it to not visible. Thankfully though I didn't have to move my entire click listener code from the fragment to the adapter.